# is a Telegram message able to open and IOS or Android App

Tags: android, ios, telegram, telegram-bot

Good day,

I developed my first Android App and the IOS is under the way.
I am using a domotic box (Jeedom). When an alarm is trigged a Telegram message is sent to some users with the temperature status. I am a using bot.

My android ans IOS app is showing the localization of the stations, and of course the temperatures.

The bot send a message. I wonder, if it is possible to define a Telegram message with link to open the installed App. As if I send a link to a web site, the link would open the installed Android or IOS app.

That would be great.
Many thanks

Comment: you want to send the link of the app to the user or a link of any website and when pressing it goes to your app ?

Comment: No I would like to send a Telegram message to the user. I would like, the user to be able to open the App from the Telegram message. Is there a way to as something like a link to the Telegram message, which will open the installed app?

Comment: Can't you send a deep link using those transparent buttons?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, I am sorry, I am novice but what's a "deep" link. I have never heard about deep link

Comment: Ok, I see, a deep link is like a button give option to the user. Then I have to investigate how a deep link can open a local installed app